Set email worker to send email data via API using fetch POST, but it triggers GET instead
I want to create an email worker by passing the incoming email from my domain, e.g., support@example.com, to an external API, but it triggers GET instead of POST when tested using email worker simulation.

Here is the relevant code:
export default {
  async email(message, env, ctx) {
    // Extract the sender and subject
    const sender = message.from;
    const headers = Object.fromEntries(message.headers);

    // Extract raw email content
    const rawEmail = await new Response(message.raw).text();

    // Prepare payload for the API
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      subject: headers.subject,
      name: sender,
      email: sender,
      message: rawEmail,
    });

    // API Call with Basic Authentication
    const apiResponse = await fetch("https://example.com/api/inboxes/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Basic secret",
      },
      body: payload,
    });

    // Check API response
    if (!apiResponse.ok) {
      console.error("API Call Failed. Status:", apiResponse.status);
      const errorText = await apiResponse.text();
      console.error("Error Response Body:", errorText);
      message.setReject("Failed to process email.");
    } else {
      console.log("Email processed and forwarded to API.");
    }
  },
};


"it triggers GET instead of POST"... how are you verifying this? It could be due to the trailing slash in your URL which depending on server configuration could result in a redirect. Are you sure that's correct?

I have edited the question with screenshot @Phil, thanks

Not enough info to help. You sure that’s not just a failing preflight due to the 307?
